# Open file from the Dock using a non-default app

Tags: applications, macos, dock

Is it possible to open a file from the Dock using a non-default app?

For example, I prefer most `.pdf` files to open in Preview (thus it is my default), but some need to be opened in Adobe Reader. Is there a key combination shortcut (for example) to bring up the "Open With" list when opening the file from the Dock?

I would prefer not to have to go to the folder in Finder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yosemite, I can open a file with any application in the Dock by dragging the file's icon over the application while holding the command and option keys down.
This only works if the targeted application is indeed able to open the file, of course.

Another option, when the application is not currently in your Dock, is to click the file with the right mouse button and choose an application from the submenu `Open with`, which is the second item in the context menu. This submenu lists the applications that can open the file you clicked on, with the default one at the top.